# select statement between ignoring condition

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

i have this query .. it always selecting all rows with between condition ignoring the type condition before

```
SELECT * FROM courses where course_type = 'ad' and (daily between 0 and 5000) OR (monthly between 0 and 5000)
```

it always return the all rows ignoring this

```
course_type = 'ad'
```

what am i missing? i know it will be something stupid and primitive/basic BUT i can't focus ADHD is killing me plus 2 days without sleep

thanks to everyone in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to learn about how boolean expressions are parsed.  Your expression requires additional parentheses:

```
where course_type = 'ad' and 
      ( (daily between 0 and 5000) OR (monthly between 0 and 5000) )
```

Until you better understand boolean expressions, I would suggest that you always use explicit parentheses when you are mixing `AND`s and `OR`s.